# How to prove whether $\;\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \left((ia + b)xk\right)dk\;$ does not converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

According to Mathematica, the following integral does not converge:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp \left((ia + b)xk\right)dk
$$

Though this makes sense intuitively (I see it as an oscillation of ever increasing amplitude for increasing k), I am looking for the best way to show analytically that it does indeed not converge, however I am unfamiliar with the typical methods for doing so.

Note that ideally this would be a method which can also be applied to multidimensional cases like

$$
\int_{all space} \exp \left(\boldsymbol k^T \left[-i\mathbf A \boldsymbol x + \mathbf B \boldsymbol x\right]\right)
$$

which is the problem which I am actually faced with.

Thank you for any pointers to applicable methods!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will split this up and redefine constants to show the point:
$$\alpha=ax,\beta=bx,s=\alpha+\beta i$$
or to be more general:
$$s\in\mathbb C$$
so we have:
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb R}e^{sk}\,dk=\underbrace{\int\limits_{\mathbb R^-}e^{sk}\,dk}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int\limits_{\mathbb R^+}e^{sk}\,dk}_{I_2}$$
now notice that in order for $I_1$ to converge we require $\Re(s)>0$, but for $I_2$ to converge we require $\Re(s)<0$ so we have a contradiction

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it diverges. It can be shown by evaluating the integral.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{xk(b+ia)}dk$$
Assume that, $x\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$
Substitute $u=xk \implies dk=\frac{du}{x}$.
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{u(b+ia)}du$$
Clearly the anti derivative of $e^{ux}$ w.r.t $x$ will be $\frac{e^{ux}}{u}$.
So the anti derivative of required integral will be,
$$\frac{e^{u(b+ia)}}{b+ia}$$
Which diverges as $u\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Since all applicable methods to solve the problem are welcomed, I posted the above answer.